# Prove the following $A \setminus (B\setminus C) = (A\setminus B)\cap (A \cup C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I want to prove the following so I decide to rewrite the RHS 
$$A \setminus (B\setminus C) = (A\setminus B)\cap (A \cup C)$$
$$
A\setminus(B\setminus C) = A\setminus (B \cap C^c) = A\cap (B\cap C^c)^c = A\cap(B^c\cup C) = (A\cap B^c)\cup(A\cap C)
$$
there is way that $(A\cap B^c)\cup(A\cap C)\rightarrow (A\setminus B)\cup(A\cap C) = (A\setminus B)\cap (A \cup C)$?

 thanks.
EDIT

LHS:
$$x\in A \vee x\in A\cap C \rightarrow x\in A \wedge x\in C$$
RHS:
$$x\in A \wedge x\in A\cup C \rightarrow x\in A \vee x\in C$$

how it can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $A=B=C=\{1\}$.

$B\setminus C=\{1\}\setminus\{1\}=\emptyset$.
$A\setminus(B\setminus C)=\{1\}\setminus\emptyset=\{1\}$.

$A\setminus B=\{1\}\setminus\{1\}=\emptyset$.
$A\cup C=\{1\}\cup\{1\}=\{1\}$.
$(A\setminus B)\cap(A\cup C)=\emptyset\cap\{1\}=\emptyset$.

$A\setminus(B\setminus C)=\{1\}\ne\emptyset=(A\setminus B)\cap(A\cup C)$.

That's why you have trouble proving it.

You could have found this counterexample by drawing the Venn diagram, and observing that the equality fails when some element is in all three sets.

Alternatively, you could simplify the right side: $A\setminus B\subseteq A$ and $A\subseteq A\cup C$, so $A\setminus B\subseteq A\cup C$, so $(A\setminus B)\cap(A\cup C)=A\setminus B$, so the alleged identity simplifies to$$A\setminus(B\setminus C)=A\setminus  B$$which, if true, would mean that $C$ has nothing to do with it. Seems unlikely. If you specialize by setting $C=B$, you get  the alleged identity$$A=A\setminus B$$which is blatantly false.